# Open subset of $\mathcal{L}(H)$?

Tags: general-topology, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $H$ be a Hilbert  space . Denote $\mathcal{L}(H)$ the vector space (on the field $\mathbb{C}$) of all bounded linear maps on $H$ into $H.$ Define the subset $K \subset \mathcal{L}(H) $ by 
$$K := \{A \in \mathcal{L}(H); \sigma(A) >0\},$$
where $\sigma(A)$ denotes the spectrum of $A.$

Is $K$ an open subset of $\mathcal{L}(H)$ ?

Comment: By $\sigma(A)>0$, do you mean that all the elements in the spectrum satisfy $\Re(\lambda)>0$, or that all the elements in the spectrum are real and positive?

Comment: All elements are real positive. If we take $A \in K$ and consider $A+\epsilon iId,$ would this contradicts that the ball $B(A,r) \subset K$ for any $r>0$ ?

Comment: @A.MONNET I think you have hit the nail on its head. The element $A \in K$ does not have any open neighborhood in $\mathcal{L}(H)$ that is entirely contained in $K$, and hence $K$ can not be open.

Answer (score 0):

A famous result of Newburgh says:

If $U$ is an open set in $ \mathbb C$ and if $ \sigma(A) \subset U$ then there is $ \delta >0$ such that $||A-B|| < \delta$ implies  $ \sigma(B) \subset U$.

(upper semicontnuity)

Newburgh: Variation of spectra. Duke. Math. J, $18 (1951), 165-167$

Comment: but $(0, +\infty)$ is not an open set in $\mathbb{C}$ !

Answer (score 0):

Consider the one-dimensional Hilbert space $\mathbb{C}^1$. The operators acting on it are represented by $1\times 1$ matrices $(z)$, and the topology of $L(H)$ is just the topology of $\mathbb{C}$. The spectrum of  matrix $(z)$ is the point $z$ itself. So, the set of all operators with the spectrum contained in some set $A\subset\mathbb{C}$ cannot be open unless $A$ is open. In particular, for $A=(0,\infty)$ it is not open.

Conversely, if $A$ is open, then by the result cited by Fred the set of operators with spectrum contained in $A$ is open.

Answer (score 0):

For $I=id_H$ we have $\sigma (I)=\{1\}\subset \mathbb R^+ .$  For $0\ne r\in \mathbb R$ we have $\sigma ((1+r\sqrt {-1}\;)I)=\{1+r\sqrt {-1}\;\}\not \subset \mathbb R^+$ and $\|I-(1+r\sqrt {-1}\;)I\|=|r|$. So $I\in K \cap \overline {K^c}.$

Comment: My edit of the Q was for a trivial typo. "And" in the last line changed to "an".

Comment: Thank you very much. I think we have the same idea in the second comment on the main question.

Comment: Yes. The same idea. I probably overlooked that comment.